# What does db.bind actually do with MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I installed [mongoskin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoskin) package,and this is the example from npmjs

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_tests", {native_parser:true});
db.bind('article');
db.article.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
        db.close();
});
```

From github

```
 * @param {String} name the collection name
 * @param {Object} [options] collection options
 * @return {SkinCollection} collection
 */
SkinDb.prototype.bind = function (name, options) {
  return this[name] = this.collection(name, options);
}
```

I am even more confused with his example(Azat Mardan's book)

```
db.bind('messages').bind({
  findOneAndAddText: function (text, fn) { // no fat arrow fn because we need to let bind pass the collection to use this on the next line... this can be replaced with db.messages too
    this.findOne({}, (error, document) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return process.exit(1)
      }
      console.info('findOne: ', document)
      document.text = text
      var id = document._id.toString() // We can store ID in a string
      console.info('before saving: ', document)
      this.save(document, (error, count) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error)
          return process.exit(1)
        }
        console.info('save: ', count)
        return fn(count, id)
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Why do we need second bind?

What does bind actually do? Binding database serves for what?

Comment: according the readme (https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin) its an alias for `db.collection(name, options)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the readme (https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin):

example from the readme:

```
db.bind('article').bind({
    getByAuthor: function(author_id, callback) {
        this.findOne({author_id: author_id}, callback);
    }
});
db.article.getByAuthor(author_id, function(err, article) {
        console.log(article);
});
```

`db.bind('xxx')` is the collection (so you can now use `db.xxx`).
after `.bind({name: function(...)})` you can use `db.xxx.name`

But this is all written in the readme.